# sql - query for all values in table with limit

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have an SQL query which I run in Amazon Athena:

```
select 
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
from
    T
where
    A = '1000'
order by
    B desc
limit 1
```

where I order by `B` and take the first row only for the value `1000` for `A`. However I want to run this query for all values of `A` in `T` i.e for each `A` in `T` get the first row only and append to the results.

How do I do this?

Example of table data:

```
A     B           C D
1000 '12/01/2021' 1 7
1000 '10/01/2020' 2 8
1333 '06/01/1920' 3 9
1333 '07/01/1920' 4 10
1999 '09/03/1960' 5 11
1999 '09/03/1950' 6 12
```

and the result I want to get is:

```
1000 '12/01/2021' 1 7
1333 '07/01/1920' 4 10
1999 '09/03/1960' 5 11
```

Comment: you want to only top one value right ?

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya No, I want to run that query for all the values of `A`, not just 1000 in that example. So the original query returns 1 row only but I want to append each row for each value of `A` to the result.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: How come you want the 07/01/1920 row and not the 06/01/1920 row, for id 1333? Now I see, you want the last row for each id.

Comment: @jarlh The row chosen should be the one with the latest date i.e 07/01/1920 because it's `desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to make it.

```
SELECT A,
    B,
    C,
    D
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B DESC) rn
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```